# is there way to set submitted property of form in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<form #formRef="ngForm" novalidate (submit)="isvalid()">
```

This is the form that we have..
And in the component class

```
 @ViewChild('formRef') form: NgForm;
```

Whenever the form is submitted , the isvalid method is invoked which checks some validations . 
There is a property on form 'submitted' which tells if the form is submitted or not

How can set the property 'submitted'to false from a component;from inside my isValid method programatically ? I dont want to clear any values.Its just this property.

Comment: Im not 100% clear on exactly what youre asking for

Comment: How to set the form's submitted property true/false manually with an angular component?

Answer (score 0):

If I think I follow what youre doing;

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submit()" #f="ngForm" style="width:100%;">
    <input matInput placeholder="Age" name="age" [(ngModel)]="model.age" #age="ngModel" type="number" required>
    <input matInput placeholder="Hours drinking" name="hoursdrinking" [(ngModel)]="model.hoursdrinking" #hoursdrinking="ngModel" type="number" required>
    <div *ngIf="error" class="alert" [ngClass]="{'alert-danger': over, 'alert-warning' : under, 'alert-success': sober}" [innerHTML]="error"></div>
    <button [disabled]="loading" mat-raised-button color="accent">Submit</button>
    <img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
</form>
```

What I have is a form, that will only submit when its valid and submit is called, some basic inputs that are mapped to a model and a loading bar, error/success message

Here is an example form I have, in my component here is what I have:

```
model: any = {};
loading = false;
error = '';
```

And when you want to submit here is what I have as an example:

```
submit() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.sendForm().subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if(data.includes('Success')) {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.error = data;
                    this.sober = true;
                    this.over = false;
                    this.under = false;
                }
                if(data.includes('Warning')){
                    this.error = data;
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.sober = false;
                    this.over = false;
                    this.under = true;
                }
                if(data.includes('Danger')) {
                    this.error = data;
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.sober = false;
                    this.over = true;
                    this.under = false;
                }
            },  //changed
            (err)=> {
                console.log(err);
                this.error = 'Something went wrong';
                this.loading = false;
            },
            ()=>console.log("Done")
        );
    }

    public sendForm() {
        var postData = "age=" + this.model.age
            + "&gender=" + this.model.gender
            + "&weight=" + this.model.weight
            + "&height=" + this.model.height
            + "&fitness=" + this.model.fitness
            + "&hoursDrinking=" + this.model.hoursdrinking
            + "&otherC=" + this.model.standard
            + "&beerC=" + this.model.beer
            + "&wineC=" + this.model.wine
            + "&spiritsC=" + this.model.spirits
            + "&alcopopC=" + this.model.alcopop
            + "&ciderC=" + this.model.cider;
        let headers: Headers;
        headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this.http.post('/php/calculator.php', postData, {headers: headers})
            .map((res:any) => res.text())
    }
```

With my submit I tired to put a big example of something useful I personally used.
Its a calculator, on submit it will use the 'sendForm()' function and subscribe to it, then check the data and send a response, if the data contains a certain string value, that will determine what class is set to the line here we have in our form:

```
<div *ngIf="error" class="alert" [ngClass]="{'alert-danger': over, 'alert-warning' : under, 'alert-success': sober}" [innerHTML]="error"></div>
```

Its set as innerHTML because my result from my php file contains  and 
 so i want that formatted correctly when recieved!

Hope this helps you

You can see this in action here:

https://callum.tech/#/bac

Comment: where is portion for setting submitted of form? This doesn't seem relate to my question

Comment: we get the data with the model, then use this.model.* to do things with it in submit() when its called

Comment: thats not my question.. Its about ngForm's specific 'submitted' property